# How to import massively taxonomy terms?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, importing-exporting

I have taxonomy terms installed and there I have article categories listed.

I have a lot of categories and articles. Now I need to import more categories from .txt file.

What is the best way to do this? I don't want to create these categories one by one.

Comment: Drupal version?

Comment: finally, do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I use in every of my projects the [Taxonomy Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) module, among its features you can find:

- mass adding of new terms
- dynamic treeview
- mass deleting
- moving of terms in hierarchies